# Rails cocoon gem issue with jquery mask: new entry created every time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, maskedinput, cocoon-gem

I am using Cocoon 1.1.1 to nest phone fields for a `Person` model. I wanted to have a input mask for the phone number, so I included `jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js` under the javascript folder.

It seems that when I apply the mask, the parameters submitted to Rails is missing the `id` for the phone attributes:

```
 "phones_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"number"=>"214-648-4417", "label"=>"Work", "_destroy"=>"", "id"=>''}}}
```

This creates new entries every time. At this point, I am not adding new phone numbers, just clicking on Update.

This is my Coffee Script:

```
jQuery.fn.addPhoneMasks = ->
  $('input[id*="phone"]').each ->
    $(this).mask("999-999-9999?")

jQuery ->
  $('div#phones').addPhoneMasks()
```

(Note: I would need to use insertion callbacks to apply the mask to newly inserted phone fields, but I am not there yet :) )

Answer (score 0):

I found my error: the mask should not use `id*="phone"` because the jquery plugin adds a value  to the hidden fields of cocoon.

My solution is to make a class for the phone, and then use this to for the selection.